# ListView is empty/disapears after Orientation Change even if Adapter contains Items

Tags: java, android, xml

I got a ListView with a custom Adapter.
In the Adapter a layout is inflated from xml.

All works fine, and I can see the items, until the Screen Orientation is changed.
I know that the Activity is recreated (or resumed) then, and the ListView is recreated too, as well as the Adapter.
But there are no items in the ListView now. The Adapter isn't empty, I use toasts to display the count of items in the Adapter.

I guess there is an inflating problem, because if I use the same Adapter (or an adapter with the same data) to a new ListView nothing is shown as well.
But the most crazy thing I don't understand is, that if I let my getView() method return a simple TextView, all works fine, even after orientation change.

I tried several things, like don't recycle a View so that it is inflated every time, or save the View to the matching Item (from getItem(position) from the Adapter).

I'm grateful for all hints :)

EDIT: so I was asked for some code.

Here is the getView() of my Adaptar

```
            @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final Event event = getItem(position);  
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_event_item_layout, parent,
                    false);
            view.setTag(R.id.eventDate, view.findViewById(R.id.eventDate));
            view.setTag(R.id.eventTime, view.findViewById(R.id.eventTime));
            view.setTag(R.id.eventName, view.findViewById(R.id.eventName));
            view.setTag(R.id.eventBemerkungen,
                    view.findViewById(R.id.eventBemerkungen));
            view.setTag(R.id.eventIcon, view.findViewById(R.id.eventIcon));

        }


        ((TextView) view.getTag(R.id.eventDate)).setText(event.getDate());

        ((TextView) view.getTag(R.id.eventTime)).setText(event.getName());
        ((TextView) view.getTag(R.id.eventName)).setText(event.getTime());

        ((TextView) view.getTag(R.id.eventBemerkungen)).setText(event
                .getDescription());

        SquaredImageView icon = (SquaredImageView) view.getTag(R.id.eventIcon);

        Picasso.with(context).load(event.getUri())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_reload).into(icon);
        view.setBackgroundColor(event.getBackgroundColor());

        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return view;
        //return getDummyTextView();
    }
    public TextView getDummyTextView()
    {
        TextView tv=new TextView(context);
        tv.setText("YOLO BIATCHSES");
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        return tv;
    }
```

Comment: post your code and logcat

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same exact problem although it wasn't because of orientation change and I found the solution by just setting `listView.setAdapter(adapter)` again after the recreation of the activity or whatever case you have. I suspect the listview is basically losing the pointer to the adapter.